# ASP.NET Core API - Second operation is started on Db context before a previous operation completed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm receiving the following exception on ASP.NET core app:

"An attempt was made to use the context while it is being configured. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside 'OnConfiguring' since it is still being configured at this point. This can happen if a second operation is started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."

I know the reason why it is generating that error. Multiple threads in my app are at the same time trying to initialize DBContext i.e. from the frontend, receiving multiple requests all accessing the same method

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> QueryAsync<T>(string sqlStmt, Parameter[] inputParameters = null)
    {
        if (inputParameters is null)
            return await Database.GetDbConnection().QueryAsync<T>(sqlStmt);
        paramsList = new DynamicParameters();
        paramsList.AddParamater(inputParameters);
        return await Database.GetDbConnection().QueryAsync<T>(sqlStmt, paramsList);  <--Here the exception is raised
    }
```

If wondering what is that 'Database' referring to, then it is a DatabaseFacade type property inside DbContext class of EFCore 6.0.9; here's the code:

```
namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore{
public class DbContext :
    IInfrastructure<IServiceProvider>,
    IDbContextDependencies,
    IDbSetCache,
    IDbContextPoolable
{
    private readonly DbContextOptions _options;

    private IDictionary<(Type Type, string? Name), object>? _sets;
    private IDbContextServices? _contextServices;
    private IDbContextDependencies? _dbContextDependencies;
    private DatabaseFacade? _database;

/// <summary>
    ///     Provides access to database related information and operations for this context.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual DatabaseFacade Database
    {
        get
        {
            CheckDisposed();

            return _database ??= new DatabaseFacade(this);
        }
    }
 }}
```

I'm injecting DBContext in the ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs, hence I cannot create multiple DBContexts for each thread.

Also, service lifetime for DBContext is set to transient when configuring the context:

```
services.AddDbContextFactory<MyQueryDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(MyQuery, sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(databaseTimeout)), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

Where MyQueryDbContext looks like this:

```
public class MyQueryDbContext  : MyDbCtx<MyQueryDbContext>, IMyQuery
{
    public MyQueryDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyQueryDbContext> model) : base(model)
    {
    }
}
```

And here's the MyDbCtx:

```
public class MyDbCtx<TContext> : DbContext
{
    public MyDbCtx(DbContextOptions<TContext> model) : base(model)
    {
    }
}
```

So, I'm not explicitly overriding OnConfiguring method as I'm providing config details from outside

I can make that async method run synchronously but what other options do I have?

Comment: Where does `Database` come from and how is it used? The code you posted doesn't show any attempt to use DbContext from multiple threads though. It shows an attempt to use Dapper on top of EF Core instead of just opening a connection. That won't create the error you got. Making this method synchronous *won't* fix the bug, which is using DbContext as a DbConnection

Comment: Please post your `OnConfiguring` code and how you call `QueryAsync`. This code is a misuse of EF Core - a DbContext isn't a database connection, it's a short-lived Unit-of-Work, tracking and persisting all changes made in a *single* business/application "transaction". It's not meant to be used from multiple thread because it doesn't need to. It's not an alternative to using a SqlConnection either

Comment: Many a times this error is result of a loop, where next iteration is executed before the first one completes. Debug and see if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved after adding the service of the type, which contained the exception-raising method, as 'scoped' in startup. Missed that it was being added as singleton